# Query with group by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on the following user table, where role = 2 means the user is an instructor, and role = 3 means that the user is a student.

```
+--------+------+---------------+
|  name  | role | creation_date |
+--------+------+---------------+
| Tom    |    2 | 2020-07-01    |
| Diana  |    3 | 2020-07-01    |
| Rachel |    3 | 2020-07-01    |
| Michel |    3 | 2020-08-01    |
+--------+------+---------------+
```

My goal is to select the sum value of all instructors and students, grouped by date. The result should look like this:

```
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
| totalInstructors | totalStudents | creation_date |
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
|                1 |             2 | 2020-07-01    |
|                0 |             1 | 2020-08-01    |
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

In this case, on 2020-07-01, I had 1 instructor and 2 students registered and on 2020-08-01, I had no instructors and I had 1 student registered.

My problem is that I am having difficulties in setting up this query, if someone can help me thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need count with a case statement as follows

```
select count(case when role=2 then 1 end) as totalInstructors 
      ,count(case when role=3 then 1 end) as totalStudents 
      ,creation_date 
  from tbl
group by creation_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    creation_date,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN role = 2 THEN 1 END) AS totalInstructors,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN role = 3 THEN 1 END) AS totalStudents
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    creation_date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

A simple GRoupBY and SUM helps

This works. because the compasison role = 2 gives 1 back it it tue and 0 if it is false

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `name` VARCHAR(6),
>   `role` INTEGER,
>   `creation_date` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`name`, `role`, `creation_date`)
> VALUES
>   ('Tom', '2', '2020-07-01'),
>   ('Diana', '3', '2020-07-01'),
>   ('Rachel', '3', '2020-07-01'),
>   ('Michel', '3', '2020-08-01');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     SUM(`role` = 2) totalInstructors ,
>     SUM(`role` = 3) totalStudents,
>    `creation_date`
> FROM table1
> GROUP BY `creation_date`
> ORDER BY `creation_date`
> ```
>
> ```
> totalInstructors | totalStudents | creation_date
> ---------------: | ------------: | :------------
>                1 |             2 | 2020-07-01   
>                0 |             1 | 2020-08-01
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=50e3e1e1c467079006f65355367da3ee)*

Comment: Is a good approach to the problem, it worked very well! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select 
case when role = 2 then count(1) end as totalInstructors,
case when role = 3 then count(1) end as totalStudents,
creation_date
from table_name
group by  creation_date;
```

You can use `COALESCE()` to replace null with 0

```
select COALESCE(totalInstructors, 0) as totalInstructors, COALESCE(totalStudents, 0) as totalStudents,creation_date
from
(select 
case when role = 2 then count(1) end as totalInstructors,
case when role = 3 then count(1) end as totalStudents,
creation_date
from table_name
group by  creation_date) qry;
```